# error: expected unqualified-id before 'while'|

Tags: c++

Keep Getting This Error On Line 12

```
#include <iostream>

int num = 1;
int number;
int total = 0;
while (num<=5){
    cin >> number;
    total +=number;
    num++;
    cout<< total<<endl
}
```

Comment: Looks like you may be missing a function to contain  that code.

Comment: In C++ language *statements* are supposed to be written *inside functions*. You can't just write an interation statement (your `while`) in the middle of a file.

Comment: There's only 11 lines, so line 12 marks end-of-file. Note that C++ syntax restricts executable statements to bodies of functions.

Comment: By definition, a C++ program needs a `main` function, as `main` is the first function executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a `int main(void)` function in which all of your code should be inside. By definition, a C++ program is **required** to have a `int main(void)` function. You need to put all your code inside the `int main(void)` function.

Also, your `cin <<` and `cout <<` statements are missing the namespace tag `std::`. Therefore, you need to add the `std::` at every instance you use `cin` or `cout` See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) // The main() function is required in a C++ program
{
    int num = 1;
    int number;
    int total = 0;
    while (num <= 5)
    {
        std::cin >> number; // You need to add the reference to std:: as "cin <<" is a part of the std namespace
        total += number;
        num++;
        std::cout << total << std::endl // You need to add the reference to std:: as "cout <<" and "endl <<" is a part of the std namespace
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: int main(void) function does not return a value. It will work, but it's not the C++ standard. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: @SantiagoVarela, It is standard C++ that `main` (nothing else, only `main`) returns 0 when reaching the end of the function.

Comment: How does that conflict with my comment @chris? I am referring to the main function and quoting a source...

Comment: @SantiagoVarela, You said it wasn't standard C++ to fall off the end of `main`. I'm saying it is, and your reference agrees: *4) The body of the main function does not need to contain the return statement: if control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;.*

Comment: I realized I was missing the main comment,silly me.now I'm getting a different error when I try to run the code.it says ||=== Build: Debug in First C++ App (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||error: can't create obj\Debug\main.o: Permission denied|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
any help on this?

Comment: @EliteDeity how are you building it? Use **sudo** before your build command.

Comment: this is my first attempt at c++ so idk all the terms.whats sudo?

Comment: @chris You're right. It's not standard, but I guess it's a opinion of taste. If my main function is returning an int, I like reading it's returning a successful exit, with the code **0**. In the C Programming language, an exit status of 0 (zero) stands for successful execution, while 1 (one) (usually) or any other number stands for an error. I guess this "legacy" has been carried over to C++.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer the feeling is mutual. I also got down voted, with no explanation.

Comment: @EliteDeity That is probably because the console application is running in the background. The result is a conflict of multiple tasks running. Try cancelling/stopping all other build/run tasks, and then try again.

Comment: @SantiagoVarela Sorry about that, your comment coincided with the downvote, so I thought that was your downvote.

Comment: I tried closing everything via task manager and restarting,still get error.and ok sorry.ill click it

Comment: @EliteDeity Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammerIm Using CodeBlocks

Comment: @EliteDeity Try the following links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921297/codeblocks-c-build-permission-denied-collect2-exe ; http://www.metalshaperman.com/?p=180 ; The first one is on StackOverflow, and the second one is a separate blog. They both address the error you got in your program